# click on option in a select with selenium library in python

Tags: python, selenium

I try several ways (css, xpath, value, text) in oder to click on one option on any select field in this website:

https://www.ovh.com/auth/signup/#/?ovhCompany=ovh&onsuccess=https:%2F%2Fwww.ovh.com%2Fmanager%2F

Do you have any idea on what can block ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**Import :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

**to select country :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.ovh.com/auth/signup/#/?ovhCompany=ovh&onsuccess=https:%2F%2Fwww.ovh.com%2Fmanager%2F")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
select  = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME , "ovh_field_country"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("Anguilla")
```

**to select type of content :**

```
select  = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME , "ovh_field_legalform"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("Company")
```

same way you can proceed further. [Reference link](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/basics-of-webdriver/handling-dropdowns/)